# unable to display foreign key relationship in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model Project, Tasks, and Project has many Tasks, I'm trying to list all tasks under each project.

```
GET /api/project/ 

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Project 2",
        "task": [
            3
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Project 1",
        "task": [
            4,
            2,
            1
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm unable to display details of each Task, Task name, description, status ..etc

Here is my Serializer

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from api.models import Project, Task


class ProjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'task'
            )


class TaskSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

Here is my Model

```
class Project(models.Model):

    # Fields
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # Relationship Fields
    #user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name


class Task(models.Model):

    # Fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # Relationship Fields
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', related_name='task' )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about nested serializers http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects. You need to add `TaskSerilizer` to your `ProjectSerializer`

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from api.models import Project, Task

class TaskSerializer(ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = Task

class ProjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    task = TaskSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'task'
        )
```